call onclicklistener for scecifiv item in CardView using Kotlin
I write an App in Kotlin. I use recyclerview and cardview.
My cardview has 3 TextFields (pname, psumme and pplatz) and 1 EditText.
I would like to fire an onclicklistener only, when I click the TextField pname, not when clicking anywhere else.
I find lots of examples here, where I click the cardview and this works. The clicklistener has to be included in the onindViewHolder.
So, my question is, if it is possible to fire this listener ONLY, when clicking the pname-field
I tried to write an listener for the pname-field, but didn't work.
I hope, there is a way for firing the listener for the pname-field
This is my cardview
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mycardview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/green1"
    app:cardElevation="1dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Spieler"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Itzzzzem"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/PunkteRunde"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:editable="false"
        android:elegantTextHeight="false"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:inputType="numberSigned"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="100"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Punkteletzte"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="100"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PunkteGesamt"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="10000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Platz"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Platz"
        android:textSize="20sp" />


</LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
One Card is one line in my recyclerview.
In mainActivity I have a button to add a card. This button calls an InputPopUp window to enter a name. There I check the validity of the name (not empty, not double )
fun Spieler(view: View) {
    var medin = ""
    if (inpopup == 2) {
        var medin = toptext
        inpopup = 1
    }
    if (toptext != "toptext") {
        medin = toptext
    }
    inputPopup(medin)
}

The simple thing, I want to do is:
when selecting a card with onclicklistener, the click should only fire, when I select the TextField pName, because then I can call my InputPopUp in mainActivity, where my logic to check validity is embedded.
(if I make pName an EditText, I could edit the name, but can not check it against other names?)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I edited my question. I hope, it can be understood.

I checked all the related questions and others. But I think, they all deal with selecting the complete cardview, NOT with reacting only, when I select an item WITHIN the cardview?
